# Ajax search feature not working in django App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm following a tut from Mike hibbert and have tried to modify it a bit to suit my needs but it's not working. I wanted to use his way because my way was breaking the DRY rule, I had to write search logic for each of my views I thought it might be the order my js But I dont think it is. I could be wrong, as I am fairly new to prgramming. I'm not sure but i think the issue may be with my search being on the nav which I nav in an include. Heres my code

views.py

```
def search_title(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    search_text = request.POST['search_text']
else:
    search_text = ''

posts = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(title__contains=search_text)|
    Q(content__contains=search_text)
)
context = {
    "posts": posts
}
return render(request, "posts/ajax_search.html", context)
```

my nav.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">HiSPANIC HEiGHTS</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">


      <form method="POST" action=" "  class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="input-group">{% csrf_token %}
          <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" class="form-control"
          style="width: 350px">

          <ul id="search-results">

          </ul>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span style="font-size:1.4em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>
        </span>
        </div>
      </form>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'posts:sewp'  %}">Sewp</a></li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'posts:create' %}">Create</a></li>
        {% endif %}

      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
<title> {% block head_title %} try django 1.9 {% endblock head_title %}</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/base.css" %}'/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
{% include "includes/nav.html" %}



{% include "includes/messages_display.html" %}

<div class="container">

    {% if title == "posts" %}
    <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 80px">
        {% block jumbotron %}{% endblock jumbotron %}
   </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script src="{% static 'js/ajax.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.js' %}"></script>

<script>
  $("nav.navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar();
</script>
```

ajax.js

```
 $(function(){

$('#search').keyup(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/posts/search/",
        data: {
            'search_text': $('#search').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
  });
  });

  function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
     $('#search-results').html(data);
  }
```

my posts/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',   post_list, name='list'),
url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_list"),
url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
url(r'^sewp$', sewp, name='sewp'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),
url(r'^search/', search_title),
]
```

I see no errors in the network, I've switched back and forth from GET to POST, just trying to tweak things to make it work but nothing has changed. My jquery is from a CDN but I don't think that's an issue, but I am a newb and could be wrong. any help with this will be appreciated

Comment: Is that your top-level `urls.py`, or just the `posts` app's one?

Comment: @AlexMorozovit's my posts/urls.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `search` url definition to the top of the `urlpatterns` list, so it doesn't get masked by the `post_detail` wildcards:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',   post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^search/', search_title),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_list"),
    url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
    url(r'^sewp$', sewp, name='sewp'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),
]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request):

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

And your `post_detail` regexp certainly matches `search/`.

Comment: @AlexMrozov that's what it was. But now search doesn't work if I hit enter the normal way. In other words I have to select one of the choices in order for it to do the search. it also destroys the css, but thats cosmetic. I'll worry about that later

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be required to have $ at the end of your search url string.

```
url(r'^search/$', search_title),
```

This lets django know it's the end of the string. Unless you've confirmed that you've actually been able to dispatch to the search_title view.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried that but nothings changed